# Rendering fetched data to screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I built a component which uses Axios get request and retrieves a list of email addresses.

I don't know what should I write inside render() so I will be able to see the emails list over my website.

This is my suggestion:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from "react-router";
import axios from 'axios';

export class GetEmailsComponent extends Component {

state = {
    emails: []
}

componentDidMount(){
    //this.setState({emailList : undefined});
    axios.get('./api/EmailAddresses')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({emails: response.data});
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

render() { 
      return (
        <div>
            <button type = "button" onClick= {this.state.emails.map(email => <div>{email}</div>)}>GET ALL EMAILS</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I check the Console I see an array of the desired emails.
I am looking for a suggestion of how to edit my code so it will render all this mails to the screen (After the button clicked).

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your render method, you can map over `this.state.emails` and return an element for each email (At first the array will be empty, so maybe you can add a condition so you wouldn't render an empty div for no reason) Something like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.emails.map(email => <div>{email}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

As for `componentDidMount` - It's a lifecycle method of React. Anything you put there will run after the component mounts for the first time. If you want to trigger the call to Axios once the button is clicked, define a different function (like fetchEmails) and call it using this.fetchEmails.

Comment: Lovely, Toda Raba :)

Comment: `componentDidMount` is a saved word in React, meaning that function will run after the component mounts for the first time.
This means you cant trigger that function yourself, so instead you'll want to defined a separate class method which you can call with this.YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME

Comment: I see, How should I keep it as a button though ?

Comment: I believe I don't understand the question. You can still have a div with a button and an email list inside of it.

Comment: Can you please see how I edited my question ? I put it inside a button but now when I click it nothing happens..

Answer (score 1):

You have used a `componentDidMount` life cycle in react to fetch the data. And you called that method via a button. Normally we are not calling life cycle methods like this. i think its better to read the react documentation doc for get an idea about life cycles.

You can declare a function and can call that function via a button. Please find below answer.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      emails: [],
      showEmails:false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios
    .get("./api/EmailAddresses")
    .then(response => {
       this.setState({ emails: response.data });
       console.log(response.data);
    })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({showEmail:true})}>
         Get all mails
       </button>
       {this.state.showEmail && this.state.emails.map(email => <div>{email}</div>)}
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to stick with componentDidMount() ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like below.

You need to get emails when button is clicked so you need have custom event handler function for that but not componentDidMount method. You cannot call componentDidMount method as event handler function.

Also when you render emails in loop you need to set unique key to top element inside loop. Key can be a index or unique id from data. Looks like you don’t have unique id from emails array so you can use index as key like below

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
     import {Link} from "react-router";
     import axios from 'axios';

     export class GetEmailsComponent extends Component {

     state = {
        emails: []
     }

  getEmails = () =>{
       //this.setState({emailList : undefined});
       axios.get('./api/EmailAddresses')
         .then(response => {
             this.setState({emails: response.data});
             console.log(response.data);
         }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

     render() { 
           return (
                <div>
                    <ul>
                      {this.state.emails.map((email, index)=> <li key={"Key-"+index}>{email}</li>)}
                     </ul>
                    <button type="button" onClick={()=> this.getEmails()}>Get all mails</button>
                </div>
                 )
            }
         }
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to stick with componentDidMount() ?

Comment: In your case you don’t need to deal with componentDidMount.